# Does Microsoft Graph support OAuth 2.0 tokens in URIs?

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, odoo

I am trying to configure Odoo 11 to work with our business' directory on Microsoft Azure AD through OAuth 2.0.

Odoo 11 uses the implicit method to acquire a token - this seems to work okay and I can get a valid token from the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<company_domain>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` endpoint.

It then uses the method described in Section 2.3 of [RFC6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) to read the endpoint data. This method involves sending a query to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?access_token=<access_token>`

I know the token is valid because I can use `https://www.hurl.it` to send a query to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` with a request header of `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>` and I get the expected results. This is according to the method described in Section 2.1 of RFC6750 which is the only method I have come across in Microsoft's documentation.

If I manually try to send a request per section 2.3 I get an error response from Microsoft Graph:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Bearer access token is empty.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "2319fe00-8695-481d-8850-d1b8ed973292",
            "date": "2018-01-23T19:12:15"
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is: Does Microsoft Graph support the request method in Section 2.3 of RFC6750?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Graph supports the [Authorization Request Header Field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1) method. The [Form-Encoded Body Parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.2) and [URI Query Parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.2) methods are not supported.

It is worth noting that the Query Parameter method poses a notable security concern:

> Because of the security weaknesses associated with the URI method
> (see [Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-5)), including the high likelihood that the URL
> containing the access token will be logged, it SHOULD NOT be used
> unless it is impossible to transport the access token in the
> "Authorization" request header field or the HTTP request entity-body.

Comment: Thanks for that Marc. If I had control over Odoo's implementation I would probably change it to the Authorization Request Header Field method, but it does seem to me a little short sighted to only implement one of the standardised methods. At least I can stop mucking about with this now!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no. In the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user#4-use-the-access-token-to-call-microsoft-graph) they say:

> Once you have an access token, you can use it to call Microsoft Graph by including it in the Authorization header of a request. The following request gets the profile of the signed-in user.

No other mentions are made, and I've never seen that kind of approach mentioned.

Maybe you need some kind of proxy in between that takes the query parameter and moves it to a header?